# Error while building Expo project: No enum constant org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.PropertiesProvider.JvmTargetValidationMode.WARN¦NG

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm encountering an issue while trying to build my Expo project, and I'm getting the following error message:
`A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-modules-core'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

> No enum constant org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.PropertiesProvider.JvmTargetValidationMode.WARN¦NG
> KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'debugAndroidTest' not found.`

I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to resolve it. Can anyone provide guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to fix it?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

- I'm using Expo for my project.
- I have checked my Kotlin and Gradle configurations, but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue.
- I have tried cleaning the Gradle cache, but that didn't resolve the problem.
- It's an empty Expo project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can add classpath to dependencies, new version kotlin gradle:

android/build.gradle

```
classpath( "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.0")
```